# Return multiple values from 1 column

Tags: sql-server

I have a ResponseText column which contains the responses of users and another column called QuestionID which uniquely identifies each question. What I am working with is this:

```
|  QuestionID  |  ResponseText  |
---------------------------------
|      32      |     Billson    |  <- First Name
|      33      |     Thorn      |  <- Last Name
|      34      |   0422949333   |  <- Ph Number
|      35      |  bt@thorn.com  |  <- Email
```

I want to display the ResponseText in seperate columns depending on the QuestionID like this (QuestionID 33 will always be last name, etc):

```
|  FName   |  LName   |  Ph Number   |  Email      |
----------------------------------------------------
| Billson  |  Thorn   |  0422949333  | bt@thorn.com|
```

Right now, I have

```
SELECT dbo.ResponseInstance.ResponseText as 'FName'
FROM dbo.ResponseInstance
WHERE dbo.ResponseInstance.QuestionID = '32'
UNION
SELECT dbo.ResponseInstance.ResponseText as 'LName'
FROM dbo.ResponseInstance
WHERE dbo.ResponseInstance.QuestionID = '33'   
UNION
SELECT dbo.ResponseInstance.ResponseText as 'Phone'
FROM dbo.ResponseInstance
WHERE dbo.ResponseInstance.QuestionID = '34'
UNION
SELECT dbo.ResponseInstance.ResponseText as 'Email'
FROM dbo.ResponseInstance
WHERE dbo.ResponseInstance.QuestionID = '35'
```

However this returns one column named FName. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT
    FName = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 32 THEN ResponseText END),
    LName = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 33 THEN ResponseText END),
    [Ph Number] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 34 THEN ResponseText END),
    Email = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 35 THEN ResponseText END)
FROM ResponseInstance
```

## EDIT:

As per Eric's comment below, you need a column that identifies the person answering the question. For illustration purposes, let's say we have a `PersonID` column on `ResponseInstance`.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE ResponseInstance(
    PersonID    INT,
    QuestionID  INT,
    ResponseText VARCHAR(50),
)
INSERT INTO ResponseInstance VALUES
(1, 32, 'Billson'),
(1, 33, 'Thorn'),
(1, 34, '0422949333'),
(1, 35, 'bt@thorn.com'),
(2, 32, 'John'),
(2, 33, 'Doe'),
(2, 34, '999999999'),
(2, 35, 'johndoe@email.com')
```

Again you can still use conditional aggregate but this time, you need to group them by `PersonID`.

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    FName = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 32 THEN ResponseText END),
    LName = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 33 THEN ResponseText END),
    [Ph Number] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 34 THEN ResponseText END),
    Email = MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 35 THEN ResponseText END)
FROM ResponseInstance
GROUP BY PersonID
```

**RESULT**

```
PersonID    FName       LName       Ph Number       Email
--------- ------------ ----------- --------------- ----------------------
1           Billson     Thorn       0422949333      bt@thorn.com
2           John        Doe         999999999       johndoe@email.com
```

Comment: If you have more than one person answering these questions, how does this keep responses from the same person together?

Comment: @EricJ. The example I posted is a cut down view of the table, there is a unique identifier that ties all answers to a person.

Comment: @Mathemats I sure hope so, else this screams bad design. Next time, post all the relevant info.

Comment: @Mathemats: I don't think this answer will work.  It is not tying the related rows together using the unique identifier for the person.